# Failed to put my struct to datastore (golang)

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

here is my struct:

```
type AreaPrerequisite struct {
    SideQuestId   int // 
    SideQuestProg int // progress
}

type AreaInfo struct {
    Id                int              `datastore:""`
    Name              string           `datastore:",noindex"`
    ActionPoint       int              `datastore:",noindex"`
    Prerequisite      AreaPrerequisite `datastore:",noindex"`

    // ignored:
    DsMonsters        []byte           `datastore:"-"`
    DsStages          []byte           `datastore:"-"`
    Monsters          AreaMonsters     `datastore:"-"`
    Stages            []*StageEntry    `datastore:"-"`
}
```

and my put() call:

```
key := datastore.NewKey(c, "Area", "", int64(pArea.Id), nil)
_, err := datastore.Put(c, key, *pArea)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

It gives me the following error when try to put to DS:

```
datastore: invalid entity type
```

I checked the doc:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference

datastore:"-" should mark some non-supported fields ignored by datastore.
Don't know why it is failing.

Comment: Have you put some data with the same "Area" kind before ? If you have updated your `struct` after putting some data, the two representations might conflict and produce an error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found that I accidentally added * to pArea as arg to put() so it is passing a value instead of pointer, causing invalid entity type error.

Comment: Sir, you saved me too.

Comment: I encountered the same problem, but using PropertyList. Apparently if you pass in a PropertyList it also has to be a pointer not a value. http://stackoverflow.com/q/30792119/101923

Answer (score 4):

I've also run into that same problem, in my case I didn't put `&` before the entity to be putted.

```
key := datastore.NewKey(c, "Area", "", int64(pArea.Id), nil)
_, err := datastore.Put(c, key, &pArea)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Notice the **&** before `&pArea`

Comment: This was quite helpful. I actually added & to the object creation, then it can be omitted in the put call. E.G. myObj := &MyObj{} vs myObj := MyObj{}