# Why do I get "invalid entity type" with datastore.Put using a datastore.PropertyList in a Go AppEngine aetest?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

This test fails with `partnermerge_test.go:22: datastore: invalid entity type`

```
package bigdipper

import (
    "testing"

    "appengine/aetest"
    "appengine/datastore"
)

func TestCreateMigrationProposal(t *testing.T) {
    c, err := aetest.NewContext(nil)
    if err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer c.Close()
    if _, err := datastore.Put(
            c,
            datastore.NewKey(c, "ORDER", "order-id-1", 0, nil),
            datastore.PropertyList{}); err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs for the datastore.Put function](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Put) say:

> Put saves the entity src into the datastore with key k. src must be a
>   struct pointer or implement PropertyLoadSaver; if a struct pointer
>   then any unexported fields of that struct will be skipped. If k is an
>   incomplete key, the returned key will be a unique key generated by the
>   datastore.

This was somewhat confusing when trying to use this with a PropertyList as the `src`. A PropertyList does not implement PropertyLoadSaver, but a *PropertyList does. Adding an & before PropertyList to get a pointer to it fixes this test.

```
package bigdipper

import (
    "testing"

    "appengine/aetest"
    "appengine/datastore"
)

func TestCreateMigrationProposal(t *testing.T) {
    c, err := aetest.NewContext(nil)
    if err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer c.Close()
    if _, err := datastore.Put(
            c,
            datastore.NewKey(c, "ORDER", "order-id-1", 0, nil),
            &datastore.PropertyList{}); err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: That is incorrect. It takes a `PropertyLoadSaver`, *not* a `*PropertyLoadSaver`. That is an interface type implemented by `*PropertyList`, which is why you need to pass `&datastore.PropertyList{}` instead of `datastore.PropertyList{}`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I'll edit my answer. I see now in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference that "the *PropertyList type implements PropertyLoadSave" I didn't know a pointer to a type could implement an interface.